# When the time is up jQuery Countdown

Tags: jquery

I use [jQuery countdown (Keith-Wood)](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) for my project. I want the AJAX commands I have set to run when the countdown is complete(so when the counter = 0). Can you help with how I can do it? I never changed the default settings of the countdown timer.

```
<p class="countdown" id="<?=$product['id']?>"></p>
<script>
  $('.countdown').countdown({
    until: new Date("<?=$product['id']?>"),
    compact: true

  });
</script>
```

AJAX codes that I want to work

```
$.ajax({
  Type: 'POST',
  url: 'update.php',
  data: {
    status: 1,
    id: Id
  },
  success: function(response) {

    window.location.href = 'index.php';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the countdown option `onExpiry` to call a function in which you make your ajax call:

```
 onExpiry: ajaxFunction
```

[Countdown reference](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html)

> onExpiry: A callback function that is invoked when the countdown
>   reaches zero.

```
$('.countdown').countdown({
   until: new Date("<?=$product['id']?>"),
   compact: true,
   onExpiry: ajaxCall 
});

function ajaxCall() {

   $.ajax({
      Type: 'POST',
      url: 'update.php',
      data: {
        status: 1,
        id: Id
      },
      success: function(response) {
         window.location.href = 'index.php';
      }
   });
}
```